# Deploying SharePoint 2013 on two seperate server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I found some technical articles which mentioned that i need to have three separate servers for SharePoint production environment; - First one is for the Database, - Second server for Application, - and the third for the front-end.

But in my case i am planning to have only two servers one for the Database and the other for the application and front-end, will it still be valid to have two servers .Baring in mind that me deployment is considered somehow small with around 60 internal users and around 100 external users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a perfectly working environment. Having a 3-tier environment is often suggested in topology guides but will give you additional high availability constraints.

Just be sure to allocate enough memory & cpu on both servers (16gb for both is the bare minimum for a production environment)

You'll need to install your farm in a similar way that you would do if you had 3 servers (meaning no standalone installation) so adding another server later should that need arise will not be an issue.